# Why spacetime fabric don't tears due to mass of heavy black hole?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, spacetime, curvature, singularities

In GR, All objects create curvatures in the space-time fabric. Why space-time fabric doesn't tear due to the mass of a heavy black hole? What is it made of?

Answer (score 4):

It’s just a metaphor used in popularizations of physics. There is no material spacetime fabric to tear.  In mainstream physics, spacetime is simply made of spacetime. (Or some people will say it is made of *events*: things that happen at a particular place at a particular time.) Spacetime curvature is a mathematical expression of the fact that its geometry is non-Euclidean, not that it is filled with some curvaceous substance.

A black hole contains a *singularity* where the curvature is infinite, according to General Relativity. Such singularities may go away when we finally have a theory of quantum gravity.

Comment: @safesphere There are plenty of physicists who don't agree with you. See [“Quantum gravity takes singularity out of black holes”](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.newscientist.com/article/dn23611-quantum-gravity-takes-singularity-out-of-black-holes/amp/) for a popular summary. They’ve published their claims. Have you?

Comment: You seem to have a serious misunderstanding of the aims of a theory like loop quantum gravity. It is not a theory of quantized matter in classical spacetime but rather a theory of quantized spacetime.

Comment: I propose nothing. Loop quantum gravity is not my theory, and I did not make any point about “made up” geometry. That is your pejorative, not mine. I stand by my answer and will not reply further.